# Could not connect to mLab's MongoDB with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid, mlab

I am using Heroku with mLab.

I set my app with mLab for using MongoDB.

It didn't work in both Heroku and my local computer.

I can access to the database use command line:

```
mongo "mongodb://usrname:pass@ds333238.mlab.com:33238/heroku_4blzdg47"
```

but when I use rails with the setting in `config/mongoid.yml`:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://usrname:pass@ds333238.mlab.com:33238/heroku_4blzdg47
```

it will be errors:

```
  MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: ds333238.mlab.com:33238, delta is 0.019052, error class is #<Resolv::ResolvError: Resolv::ResolvError>, retries is 0. Node is <Moped::Node resolved_address=nil> runtime: n/a
  MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: ds333238.mlab.com:33238, delta is 0.038719, error class is #<Resolv::ResolvError: Resolv::ResolvError>, retries is 1. Node is <Moped::Node resolved_address=nil> runtime: n/a
  MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: ds333238.mlab.com:33238, delta is 0.054449, error class is #<Resolv::ResolvError: Resolv::ResolvError>, retries is 2. Node is <Moped::Node resolved_address=nil> runtime: n/a
  Rendered homes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (368.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 385ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:70222534873720 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address=nil>]>)
```

If I set `config/mongoid.yml` to local database, it works:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/app_development
```

Is there anything wrong?

Part of my gems are:

```
ruby '2.3.7'
gem 'rails', '4.1.16'
gem "mongoid", '4.0.0'
```

Comment: You are using an ancient version of Mongoid which is no longer supported. It sounds like this is a new application; if so you should be using Mongoid 7, the current Ruby driver for MongoDB, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :) I was trying to run it without update because the whole application is old. I need to take time to update it

Comment: It works well after I updated Mongoid to version 5.2 !

Answer (score 0):

It works well after I updated Mongoid to version 5.2